# What exactly is <code> in Java

Tags: java, syntax

Edit: Thanks for the quick answers. Please mark this question for deletion. It doesn't serve SO in any way.

I was reading an article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things3.html) {Listing 2. Iterating a file
} and what stumped me was the literal `<code>` written in Java! - I've never seen that before - I now get it's meaning somewhat but has it been there since beginning or is it a new feature.

I am reproducing part of the code here..

```
return new Iterable<String>() {
public <code>Iterator</code><String> iterator() {
return new <code>Iterator</code><String>() {
public boolean hasNext() {
return line != null; 
.....
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's an artifact of the listing, and not java code in itself. You can try by compiling it.

Comment: OOPS - I should have compiled it - atleast from an online java compiler!! - anyway - this question makes no sense so Please mark it for deletion!!

Comment: I don't think this question needs deletion.  You asked it, as some point someone else might wonder the same thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too narrow of a circumstance that is not likely to happen to others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an error in the HTML markup of the site. Rightclick page and view source. It's been marked up as `&lt;code&gt;Iterator&lt;/code&gt;` instead of `<code>Iterator</code>`.

This has nothing to do with Java. You might contact the site/page author to have them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a remnant of generating code using JavaDoc. The <code></code> tags are used to highlight Java code in JavaDoc, in which it generates a Courier New font.

Answer (score 0):

Haha I think it's just HTML that's mistakenly shown as Java code, it's not part of the language. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a HTML formatting error. They are trying to use their custom code tag within another code tag.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid java. I think it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

After all the correct answers an alternative explanation:

It is to protect the code by making it uncompilable. That way no-one can steal it:)